# Remove a set of dates from dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Given a data frame that has a list of dates, I want to remove dates from the second data frame.

For example:

df1 with list of dates:

```
      day              
0  2021-02-14      
1  2021-02-15      
2  2021-02-16          
3  2021-02-18        
4  2021-02-20    
5  2021-03-17
```

df2:

```
      day           X1   X2
 0  2021-02-14      1    2
 1  2021-02-15      1    3
 2  2021-02-16      2    1
 3  2021-02-17      3    2
 4  2021-02-18      4    3
 5  2021-02-19      5    4
 6  2021-02-20      2    6
 7  2021-03-17      6    7
```

Desired outcome:

```
     day           X1   X2
3  2021-02-17      3    2
5  2021-02-19      5    4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mask .isin()

```
df2[~(df2['day'].isin(df1['day']))]
```